# Writing install location to registry from installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I am using [WiX 3.6](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/75656) to create an installer.

One of the needs is to write the location of the install location to the registry in either HKCU or HKLM depending on the ALLUSERS property.

Now based on the research I have done I think the following should work

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKMU" 
             Key="Software\OpenCover" 
             Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
  <RegistryValue  Name="Location" 
                  Type="string" 
                  Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" 
                  Action="write" 
                  KeyPath="yes" />
</RegistryKey>
```

**The problem is it only works for when ALLUSERS="" i.e. HKMU is interpreted as HKCU.**

If I try a perMachine installation where ALLUSERS=1 then the entry is not written to HKLM as expected, though when I look at the installer log file I see the call to WriteRegistryValues.

```
MSI (s) (D4:14) [22:46:24:901]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=WriteRegistryValues,Description=Writing system registry values,Template=Key: [1], Name: [2], Value: [3])
Action 22:46:24: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
MSI (s) (D4:14) [22:46:24:902]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=2,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=13200)
MSI (s) (D4:14) [22:46:24:903]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-1,Key=Software\OpenCover,,BinaryType=0,,)
MSI (s) (D4:14) [22:46:24:903]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=ConsoleLocation,Value=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\,)
WriteRegistryValues: Key: \Software\OpenCover, Name: ConsoleLocation, Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\
MSI (s) (D4:14) [22:46:24:906]: Executing op: RegCreateKey()
WriteRegistryValues: Key: \Software\OpenCover, Name: , Value:
```

Can someone explain how to achieve the task I need to complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually to do with a 32 bit installer on a 64 bit platform.

When ALLUSERS="1" is used in this scenario then the registry entries, marked up with HKMU, are actually being written, but under in this case, HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\OpenCover. I suspect entries marked as HKLM are also redirected in the same manner.

Unfortunately the documentation on [WriteRegistryValues Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not explain the 32/64 bit of "magic" redirection and the information, details regarding the actual registry entry, doesn't appear in the logs.

To get an insight as to what is happening then the following article demystifies the observed behaviour [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). From this article we can see that the installer "thinks" it is writing to a folder HKLM\Software but this is actually being *"redirected"* to HKLM\Wow6432Node\Software for a 32 bit process on a 64 bit platform and hence explains why it is not reflected into the log files. The article also explains why when ALLUSERS="" and HKMU is then HKCU why the entries appear where one would expect them to be, because these entries are *"shared"* between 32 and 64 bit applications.

Comment: That's because 32 bit processes work in a virtual environment on 64 bit OS: WOW64 (Windows on Windows). Not only the registry keys are redirected but Program Files and System directory: thus a 32 bit process does not actually know it reads files from `Program Files (x86)`, it still thinks it works with `Program Files`. The installer is also subjected to these redirections. If you install 64 bit, then 64 bit msiexec is used; in case of 32 bit package, the 32 bit msiexec is used.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your installer isn't elevating (UAC enabled?) and that the write to HKLM is being redirected to HKCU.

BTW, you could also consider using the Windows Installer API from within your application to query the UpgradeCode, ProductCode, ProductInformation(INSTALLLOCATION) without the need to write a registry key to store this metadata.

Comment: HKCU is only being written when ALLUSERS="" (which is as expected), when ALLUSERS="1" then I am seeing no entry under HKLM or HKCU. The entry is for use by 3rd party build systems such as nant/msbuild such that they can launch the application during the build process and these already have a registry utility to help with scripting.

Comment: I don't think it is UAC as the code is being placed in the correct location (Program Files) when the application is ALLUSERS="1". I am confused as to why it isn't failing as there are no entries... I am going to stick a [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) on it and see what is happening. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: The logs are over 200K, however I think I worked it out - the entry is being written but under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\OpenCover - this is because, as I understand it, the installer is a 32 bit on a 64 bit machine. The application code is actually Any-CPU (except for the native COM objects) but I don't want to have multiple installers for 32/64 environments.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was common knowledge and we were troubleshooting a harder problem.

Comment: No worries, not as common as you would think. I wrote a lot of WiX installers 5-6 years ago all on 32 bit platforms, this is my first that has to deal with multiple platforms and an all-user/per-machine setup. I knew the problem was with me but I though I was just missing a setting rather than a few brain cells :) thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably want to make sure you catch up to date then on everything that has changed since Windows XP.  Bitness issues, UAC and so on can bite you.  Step 1 is to know the platform and deployment needs.  Step 2 is to know how to make Wi/WiX implement those needs.